# How do I get django to interact with html

Tags: python, html, django

So, I have the following question, I need to create a way for the object inserted within the  field to be transferred to a

within a single page but with different functions, and I managed to do this but in a way that In my opinion, it shouldn't be the best, that is, my goal is to optimize this if possible. Below is the code for the views, urls, forms, html.

And detail, I don't intend to use Java, but if this is the only or best way, I'm willing to understand.

#urls

```
from django.urls import path
from FrontEndProject import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.RenderHomePage),
    path('test/', views.PostInfoHomePage, name='PostInfoHomePage')
]
```

#views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *


def RenderHomePage(request):
    return render(request, 'HomePageBody.html')

def PostInfoHomePage(request):
    Info = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormInfo(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            Info = form.cleaned_data['PostInfo']

    else:
        form = FormInfo()

    return render(request, 'HomePageBody.html', {'form': form, 'Info': Info})
```

#forms

```
from django import forms


class FormInfo(forms.Form):
    PostInfo = forms.CharField()
```

#html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Home page
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'PostInfoHomePage' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input name="PostInfo" value="{{ form.PostInfo.value|default:'' }}">
                <button>Take info</button>
            </form>

            <p>Information: {{ Info }} </p>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```